# Check URL exists using c#

Tags: c#, url

i have been trying to find out either provide URL is available or not. Available doesnt mean domain availability i mean either URL is accessible or its not accessible

i have tested code

```
var webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                                       "http://localhost:64519/TestPage.aspx");
webrequest.Method = "HEAD";
HttpWebResponse response = webrequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

and there is some code on pageload of Testpage

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
    XDocument xmlInput = XDocument.Load(stream);
}
```

now issue is even i added HEAD in request yet it goes in to PageLoad and throws exception.

Scenario:
i have been trying to send XML to provided URL. in XML case its working fine but when i try to check that either Link is live or not it throws exception because XDocument.Load(stream); dont have XML\
surely i can solve the issue by using

```
if (stream.BaseStream.Length != 0)
{
    XDocument xmlInput = XDocument.Load(stream); 
}
```

but its not appropriate. i just want to know the link is live or not based on my research is just Add headers but even with adding headers my problem is yet there

so please some one can help me out with this or any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: How do you define "working"?

Comment: working means URL is accessible i mean its not down, its live.

Comment: where do you get "Request.InputStream"? You should be reading response stream from "response.GetResponseStream()" from the first code portion..

Comment: Request.InputStream added in TestPage so it needs to read the request to get XML. i posted scenario why i have to do this way

Comment: Is it not simply a case of making the request and then checking that the `StatusCode` of the response is 200?

Comment: Problem is not of the status code issue is when webrequest.GetResponse() this line executes it start executing code that is in page load of TestPage that i dont want. i dont want any code of Testpage(pageload) to be executed

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) classes and set the request's Method to "HEAD".

[List of other possible Methods.](http://annevankesteren.nl/2007/10/http-methods)

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:64519/TestPage.aspx");
request.Method = "HEAD";

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var success = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

Comment: i have tested this code but as i told earlier this code has issue if the provided URL has some code in Page load it went on executing it. thats i dont want i just want to check headers to make it sure that URL is accessible

Comment: @user751959, sorry mis-understood the question, updating now.

Comment: if u have read my question i said i have used already webrequest.Method = "HEAD"; but yet it executes the PageLoad code of TestPage

Comment: 4xx and 5xx errors throw an exception, so best to wrap this in a `try{} catch{}`.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a function on the fly. Hope that it works for you :)

```
public bool isValid(string url) {
    Stream sStream;
    HttpWebRequest urlReq;
    HttpWebResponse urlRes;

    try {
        urlReq = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
        urlRes = (HttpWebResponse) urlReq.GetResponse();
        sStream = urlRes.GetResponseStream();

        string read = new StreamReader(sStream).ReadToEnd();
        return true;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Url not valid
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use the GET method**

If the Website Respond your Query then Get the Response Data...

If there is no such URL then it throws the WebException Error... 
Yoiu Can catch that and do something on that...

Here i list my idea. I think it solve ur problem

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:64519/TestPage.aspx");
    webRequest.Method = "GET";

    string responseData = string.Empty;
    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
{
   //Code - If does not Exist  
}
```